# How do I access a site by IP on a CentOS server

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, domain, html

I have a `CentOS 6.3` server, running `Apache` and have `DirectAdmin` installed.

I have created what will be a new domain, but I do not have a domain name yet. For now I have created, lets say, `mydomain.com`.

Internally, `DirectAdmin` have created a structure like this

```
/home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html
```

inside this `public_html` there is an `index.html` page.

How do I access that page by IP, using a browser? 
Supposing my IP is 100.100.100.100

thanks

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to configure IP-Based Virtual Host.

You can do that by editing your `apache/httpd.conf` file, add something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 100.100.100.100:80>
ServerAdmin rubberduck@mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html
ServerName site.mydomain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/logs/site/error_log
TransferLog /var/log/httpd/logs/site/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, you can find some great information on [Apache Official Site - Virtual Host Section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html).
Just bear in mind that the `DocumentRoot` should be specified without a trailing slash.

But, just so you know, you can edit your hosts file like so:

```
100.100.100.100 host.mydomain.com
```

And then just browse to http://host.mydomain.com